# @WebMvcTest requires mocking beans unrelated to test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

My application has two controllers. Their structures look like this:

```
@RestController
public class BooksController {
    private final DataService dataService;
    private final LibraryBookService libraryBookService;

    public BooksController(DataService dataService, LibraryBookService libraryBookService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        this.libraryBookService = libraryBookService;
    }

}

@RestController
public class UsersController {
    private final DataService dataService;

    public UsersController(DataService dataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }
}
```

Both `DataService` and `LibraryBookService` are beans. They have no dependencies on each other.

I'm trying to write my tests for UsersController, and I'm using `@WebMvcTest`. I've got an `@MockBean` for the DataService so I can mock its responses:

```
@WebMvcTest
class UsersControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    DataService dataService;

    @BeforeEach
    void resetMocks() {
        Mockito.reset(this.dataService);
    }
    // ...
}
```

However when I try to run this, I get an "APPLICATION FAILED TO START" message and a warning that BooksController couldn't autowire its dependencies properly with the stack trace pointing to:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'booksController' defined in file [/path/to/my/project/target/classes/com/example/rest/BooksController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.LibraryBookService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.LibraryBookService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Why does my UserController test care about BooksController and its dependencies (or lack thereof)? I can get past this by adding a MockBean for BooksController like this:

```
@MockBean
BooksController ignored;
```

... but this doesn't seem very sustainable. As I add more and more controllers I'm going to have more and more of these irrelevant beans polluting my tests.

Is there an annotation or config I'm missing? Or am I misusing the `@WebMvcTest` entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the Controller under test as follows:

```java
@WebMvcTest(UsersController.class)
```

By specifying none, you are telling Spring that all `@Controller` beans should be added to the application context and thus the `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` you are getting.

Comment: Awesome, thanks -- that totally did the trick.

Comment: awsome simple and great answer (y)